# Object detection cross validation

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, cross-validation, yolo

I have trained my YOLO model 5 times for different train-val splits. 5-fold crossvalidation. Then each time i run it on the test data for predictions.

There are multiple classes.

The prediction outputs have this format. And i have five of these.

```py
image,class1,confidence1,boundingbox1(xmin ymin xmax ymax),class2,confidence2,boundingbox2(xmin ymin xmax ymax), etc
a 0 0.3 1064 759 1325 1007 3 0.7 801 1176 1822 1597
b 3 0.3 1024 722 1549 1130
c 9 0.7 979 1028 1213 1348 7 0.8 637 1640 1497 1920
.
.
.
```

Now i want to combine these to one output prediction.

Is there a general way on how to do this?
Anyone know how to solve this?

It should be possible to use this:

[ensemble-objdet](https://github.com/ahrnbom/ensemble-objdet/blob/master/ensemble.py)

But i cant figure out how to do it when you have many bounding boxes for the same image.

Answer (score 1):

After doing cross validation, you have to train YOLO on all of your data to build your final model.

Just to be clear, k-fold cross validation's purpose is **not** to *come up with a final model* but to test how well your model is able to get trained by a given training data and and predict on a never-before-seen data. Its purpose is to **check models**, not build models.

More details is found in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52277) from a similar question.